# Subtotal array formula does not count cells accordingly

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, subtotal

Recently i've encountered an issue with the subtotal array formula. To be more explicit, i have the following scenario:

- In my workbook i have two different sheets: **Statistics** and **Bugs**
- In the **Bugs** sheet i have a query which updates with the latest data available at that point
- This query pulls data into a table named as **Info** from which i refer only to one column named: **CreatedTime_UTC**
- Now, in the **Statistics** sheet i have two cells: **Start date - (E2)** and **End Date - (E4)**

The problem is that if i have in my query table a cell that has the same date as the **Start date** or **End date**, the following formula does not count that cell

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Info[CreatedTime_UTC],ROW(Info[CreatedTime_UTC])-MIN(ROW(Info[CreatedTime_UTC])),,1))*(Info[CreatedTime_UTC]>=E2)*(Info[CreatedTime_UTC]<=E4))
```

To be mentioned that the formula counts only visible cells. Is there a workaround, so that the formula can count cells that contain the same dates as declared in the **Start date** or **End date** cells?

```
 | Id    | CreatedTime_UTC |
 |-------|-----------------|
 | 33760 | 8/17/2018       |
 | 33742 | 8/16/2018       |
 | 33566 | 8/8/2018        |
 | 33558 | 8/7/2018        |
 | 33472 | 7/30/2018       |
 | 33466 | 7/27/2018       |
```

[image: This is the first picture where i pull the data]
  [image: This is the table column where i have the dates listed]

Comment: Yes, table column CreatedTime_UTC is filtered from most recent date to oldest. I have attached 2 images. in the first image you can see that it shows **5** bugs instead of **6** according to the second image.

Comment: I still get 6. Does pressing F9 make a difference?

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't... The only possibility (which might sound weird) is that i've created the document when i was in Europe and now i've traveled to America so maybe my laptop finds the time adjustment as an issue?.... could that be it?

Comment: If you convert the dates to Longs do you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, i have also tried with custom date formats... the problem is the same